# how to render a .ejs file and view it after bundling with webpack in node js?

Tags: javascript, node.js, webpack

This is my webpack config:

```
{
    entry: './app.js',
    output: {
      path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist'),
      filename: "bundle.js"
    },
    module: {
      rules: [
        {
          test: /\.js$/,
          exclude: /(node_modules)/,
          use: {
            loader: 'babel-loader',
            options: {
              presets: ['env', 'es2015', 'stage-2']
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    },
    plugins: [
      new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
        template: './views/index.ejs',
        hash: true,
      })
    ],
    node: {
        __dirname: false
    },
    target: 'node'
});
```

This is my server code

```
    const express = require('express');
    const app = express();
    const path = require('path');
    const port = process.env.PORT || 3000;
    app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, '..', 'public')));

    app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, '..', 'views'));

    app.set('view engine', 'ejs');

    app.get('/', (req, res) => {
      res.render('index');
    });

    app.listen(port, ()=>{
      console.log(`Live on ${port}`);
    });
```

when i build it with webpack and run it gives me error. I dont see the index.ejs working. I have tried a lot of things. Nothing is working.

Is it possible to run the output file and it starts the index.ejs? for html files it works. Help would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add this line after you set your view engine, this should do the trick..

```
app.set("view engine", "ejs");   
app.engine('.ejs', ejs);  // <-- this one
```

Apparently, it's a result of a bug in webpack and an issue was [already opened](https://github.com/webpack/webpack/issues/4009).

Comment: yes i just found that few secs ago and tried this work around and it works. Thank you very much :)